# Installing Windows onto an Acer Iconia Tab 8 W W1-810

Tags: windows, android, tablet

I recently acquired a used Acer Iconia Tab 8 W W1-810, which is supposed to come with Windows 8.1.  Upon arrival, it had Android on it.  I have attempted to look up some sort of guide on how to put Windows back onto the tablet, but to no avail.

Is it even possible to reinstall Windows back onto the tablet?  If so, how do I, and what's the best method of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Windows RT is only available for ARM processors, so the previous answer was indeed incorrect as per magicandre1981.

That being said, unless you're able to acess the system BIOS you still won't be able to install windows 8.1 without some sort of workaround method. As per  Andre Da Costa the [Microsoft forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/install-windows-8-on-android-tablet-with-intel-cpu/4fe69cc2-061b-45e7-8e0b-58359fbe1679):

> even though it has an x86 CPU, it lacks certain hardware extensions to support Windows such as ACPI compliance.

The operating system is tied into the device's BIOS.

You should request a refund immediately.

Comment: This is supposed to be an x86 tablet; I got it specifically thinking that I could install any 32-bit version of Windows on it.  If that doesn't mean anything, then I'm going to have to return the item...

Comment: I suppose theoretically you could try to force an install of normal windows on it, but it'd probably be a roundabout/hackish method. Tablet's aren't typically programmed to have a 'select boot device' function to them.

Comment: I figured as much.  Guess I'm returning the item.  I was REALLY hoping that this was something I could fix on my own.

Comment: this is answer is crap, the tablet has a Atom x86 CPU

Comment: @magicandre198 my mistake, I forgot RT was only for ARM based tablets. I have updated the answer to better reflect the issue.

Comment: I can still get into Android Recovery Mode, so I *theoretically* should be able to reinstall Windows onto it, provided I can attach a flash drive that has an Android compatible Windows "update.zip".  But that's a LOT of work to get to work, and it would be much easier to just refund this one and purchase another tablet, as per your suggestion.

Comment: @FoxMcloud5655, Yes it's theoretically possible, but just extremely annoying. Windows doesn't have an update .zip, but rather a windows .iso file which is the digital format of a disk. Inside of that .iso file is the update executable as well as boot time execution code if the .iso file is in a usb that has been setup as a [boot key](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool).